# Get id of inserted object

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I'm defining an endpoint modeling a user as below. I can query a user by id. But how can I get that id when inserting the user? My client is written in java but I'd like to know how to retrive the id both with python as well as with the generated java client libs.

```
from google.appengine.ext import endpoints
from google.appengine.ext import ndb 
from protorpc import remote
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel

class User(EndpointsModel):
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    phone_number = ndb.StringProperty()
    reg_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

@endpoints.api(name='whereareyoudroid', 
               version='v1', description='Where Are You Users')
class UserApi(remote.Service):

    @User.method(name='user.insert', path='user')
    def insert(self, user):
        user.put()
        return user

    @User.method(request_fields=('id',), 
                 path='user/{id}', 
                 http_method='GET', name='user.get')
    def get(self, user):
        if not User.from_datastore:
            raise endpoints.NotFoundException('User not found.')
        return user
```

Comment: Are those extra front dots just artifacts of pasting the code into the question?  Please remove them if so

Comment: Yes, leftovers from vim

Comment: ok. Thanks for fixing.  Also fix `class.  UserApi`

Comment: Why is this so important?

Comment: It is bad syntax and will result in a `SyntaxError` when you run your code. I edited it so it is correct. It's important that other people can see your code and learn from it, so correct syntax is relevant.

Comment: It's just a visual representation of a tab in vim. Something I configured so I easily can distinguish from spaces. But point noted, won't happen again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## First, to answer your question:

By default, the message schema for your requests and response will be the fields on your model: `email`, `phone_number`, `reg_id`, and `created`. As is done in the [simple get sample](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/examples/simple_get.html), you can change this default to include `id` via

```
class User(EndpointsModel):
    _message_fields_schema = ('id', 'email', 'phone_number', 
                              'reg_id', 'created')
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    ...
```

or by specifying the [response fields](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/examples/matching_queries_to_indexes.html) you want returned in the `insert method`:

```
    @User.method(response_fields=('id', 'email', 'phone_number', 
                                  'reg_id', 'created'),
                 name='user.insert', path='user')
    def insert(self, user):
        user.put()
        return user
```

## Second, you have a typo/mistake in `get`:

The statement `if not User.from_datastore:` will check if the `User.from_datastore` property object on the `User` class is "truthy", which it is. You want the actual value of this property on the user object: `user.from_datastore`.